# Display customer cancelled orders count in Woocommerce Admin Edit Orders pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I'm trying to count the number of orders a customer has cancelled and disply them in the admin order screen.

My problem is that I can't get it working for remote customers, I can get it working for myself (as current_user).

This is my code (took from other googling and some small modifications):

```
function count_order_no( $atts, $content = null ) {
$args = shortcode_atts( array(
    'status' => 'cancelled',
), $atts );
$statuses    = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
$order_count = 0;
foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
    // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
    if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
        $status = 'wc-' . $status;
    }
    $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
}
ob_start();
echo number_format( $order_count );
return ob_get_clean();
} 
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'count_order_no' );
```

and then show the number in admin

```
// print the number
function print_the_number() { 
 echo do_shortcode( '[wc_order_count]' );
}

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'print_the_number', 10, 1 );
```

Any help is much apreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the Customer ID from the current order. It can be done in a much simpler way.

You should try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'get_specific_customer_orders', 10, 1 );
function get_specific_customer_orders( $order ) {

    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $order->get_customer_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array('wc-cancelled'),
    ) );

    $orders_count = '<strong style="color:#ca4a1f">' . count($customer_orders) . '</strong>';

    echo'<br clear="all">
    <p>' . __( 'Cancelled orders count: ' ) . $orders_count . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm! Indeed your way is much simpler and clearer!

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my project:
use

> **get_current_user_id()**

instead of

> **$order->get_customer_id()**

```
add_shortcode( 'geo-get-customer-orders', 'geo_get_customer_orders' );
function geo_get_customer_orders() {
    global $order;
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array('wc-completed'),
    ) );

    echo count($customer_orders);
}
```

finally use this shortcode:

> [geo-get-customer-orders]

Comment: Could you explain why you found those changes were necessary?